# Joomla htaccess rewrite url - Parameter must index by a number - Why?

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting

this is the firsttime a put a question here, so dont hard on me. Thank you.

I currently setup a joomla site. I create a page, and a new template, and a module, inside the template/index.php i call my module.

The original url that works is something like:
index.php/danh-sach-game?gt_name=game_mang_xa_hoi

danh-sach-game: is the page.
game-mang-xa-hoi: is the input parameter to the module.

everythings works find but i want to rewrite url to this:

danh-sach-game/game-mang-xa-hoi

So i created a .htaccess with content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^danh-sach-game/(.*)$ index.php/danh-sach-game?gt_name=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now this is time for "MAGIC"
if i enter the url: 
danh-sach-game/game-mang-xa-hoi
then Joomla push a message "An error has occurred.The requested page cannot be found."

But if i index the parameter by a number like this:
danh-sach-game/1-game-mang-xa-hoi (note: the number 1).
Then it works finds. Any paremeter index by a number will work find.

I rewrite url to a test file (replace index.php by test.php) than the page test.php receive the parameter as usuas, with or without number index the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Joomla and most of the Joomla extensions uses ID column of the content as an identifier to look up the database. Some of the SEF tools (for example AceSef, sh404Sef) provide the facility to lookup using the alias name (the text after the number and hyphen) however with additional cost of database queries (they will in turn query for proper url internally).

The number in the last part of the URL will be processed and passed as ID of the particular page/content that you are viewing. This is done in the particular component's router.php file.  So check the router.php file of the component you are using to check how the url gets parsed.